# Converting a create-react-app application to module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have made a React application using `create-react-app`. I would like to turn that into a React module that I can import in a different React app via `npm` - as if it was another dependency. I would love advice or steps to follow for this.

Things I have tried are

- `npm build` > `npm link` > (in diff react proj) `npm link <original_proj>`
- `npm run eject` > `npm link` > (in diff react proj) `npm link <original_proj>`

When I import in my new project and run `npm start`, I get an error saying that the import cannot be resolved.

I have found steps to create React components starting from `npm init` but I don't want to start all over again.

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard to start from `npm init`. Just reinstall dependencies and copy paste the files/code over.

Comment: yea but I lose the git history...

Comment: Not if you copy the `/.git` folder to the new project. Then you can just add, commit, and push the changes.